# Can not install oracle apex on GNU/Linux (db 12c)

Tags: oracle, linux, oracle-12c, oracle-apex

I have to install oracle apex on oracle database 12.2.0.1.0, database is on GNU/Linux server.
I followed instructions from this pages:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-application-express-apex-5-0-installation#installation]

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71588_01/HTMIG/downloading-and-installing-OracleAE.htm#HTMIG29384]

but when i came to this step:

```
@apexins.sql APEX APEX TEMP /i/
```

I got this error:

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> Performing installation in multitenant container database in the
>   background. The installation progress is spooled into apexins_cdb*.log
>   files.
>
> Please wait...
>
> catcon: ALL catcon-related output will be written to
>   [/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/apexins_cdb_catcon_64683.lst]
>   catcon: See
>   [/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/apexins_cdb*.log] files
>   for output generated by scripts catcon: See
>   [/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/apex/apexins_cdb_*.lst] files
>   for spool files, if any validate_con_names: ORCLPDB is not open
>   catconInit: Unexpected error returned by validate_con_names Unexpected
>   error encountered in catconInit; exiting
>
> Installation completed. Log files for each container can be found in:
>
> apexins_cdb*.log
>
> You can quickly scan for ORA errors or compilation errors by using a
>   utility like grep:
>
> grep ORA- *.log grep PLS- *.log

So i find solution for that error on this link:

https://learn-oracle-database.blogspot.com/2016/04/validateconnames-pdbseed-is-not-open.html

I have done, everything like is described on the link, and database was in this state:

```
SQL> select name,open_mode from v$pdbs;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OPEN_MODE
----------
PDB$SEED
MIGRATE

ORCLPDB
MIGRATE
```

And I came to final step, and executed this order:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/perl/bin/perl catcon.pl -d $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin /tmp/utl32k_output utl32k.sql
```

Then I got this error message:

> /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/admin/tmp/utl32k_output_catcon_
>   61307.lst as CATCONOUT catconInit: Unexpected error returned by set_log_file_base_path print() on closed filehandle $CATCONOUT at
>   catcon.pm line 6702. Unexpected error encountered in catconInit;
>   exiting

I tried to find solution but i could not, so if someone could help what I have to do, to solve this problem.

Comment: There are specific instructions in the APEX Installation Guide you linked to for installing in a pluggable database environment: 

**non-CDB or Locally in a PDB**, or 
**downloading and Installing Application Express in a CDB**,

Which are you trying to do?  Was there already an older version of APEX?

Comment: I am trying to install APEX in a  CDB . I have downloaded apex from oracle web page, There was no previous version of the apex on database.

Answer (score 1):

Check the status of pluggable database.

```
SQL> select name,open_mode from v$pdbs;

NAME          OPEN_MODE
------------------------------ ----------
PDB$SEED         MOUNTED
PDBORCL          MIGRATE
PDBORCL2         MIGRATE
PDBORCL1         MIGRATE

SQL> startup;

ORA-01081: cannot start already-running ORACLE - shut it down first

SQL> shutdown immediate;
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
```

Check the status of pluggable database.

```
SQL> STARTUP;
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  788529152 bytes
Fixed Size      2929352 bytes
Variable Size    541068600 bytes
Database Buffers   239075328 bytes
Redo Buffers      5455872 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> select name,open_mode from v$pdbs;

NAME          OPEN_MODE
------------------------------ ----------
PDB$SEED         MOUNTED
PDBORCL          MOUNTED
PDBORCL2         MOUNTED
PDBORCL1         MOUNTED
```

We need to start `PDB$SEED` pluggable database in `UPGRADE` state for that

```
SQL> SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;


Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.

SQL> STARTUP UPGRADE;

ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  788529152 bytes
Fixed Size      2929352 bytes
Variable Size    541068600 bytes
Database Buffers   239075328 bytes
Redo Buffers      5455872 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.

SQL> ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL OPEN UPGRADE;
Pluggable database altered.

SQL> select name,open_mode from v$pdbs;

NAME          OPEN_MODE
------------------------------ ----------
PDB$SEED         MIGRATE
PDBORCL          MIGRATE
PDBORCL2         MIGRATE
PDBORCL1         MIGRATE

SQL> exit
```

try again 
it will solve the issue

Comment: Thanks, it works now.But when  I try to install apex I get this error: set_log_file_base_path: unable to open /u01/app/oracle/apex/apexins_cdb_catcon_22831.lst as CATCONOUT